# Can I supress / hide the details pane icon in a Modern document library

Tags: document-library, modern

I have a customer who wants to hide the details pane Icon in the top right of a modern document library page so that the details pane, with the recent history, does not come flying out when a user accidentally clicks on the details pane when a document is not selected.

Is this possible ?

Or would I have to hide the icon  permanently ?  If so how do I hide the icon permanently ?

Thanks

Nigel